# In html, open a new window with selected background color

Tags: javascript, html

the html page contains 3 radio buttons- red,green, blue.If we selected any one of radio button, onw new window has to open, and that window background color should be the selected radion button color. can anyone help me how to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([demo on jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/unikel), you might need to allow popups):

HTML:

```
<label for="red">Red</label>
<input type="radio" id="red" name="windowcolor" data-color="red" />
<label for="green">Green</label>
<input type="radio" id="green" name="windowcolor" data-color="green" />
<label for="blue">Blue</label>
<input type="radio" id="blue" name="windowcolor" data-color="blue" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function openWindowWithColor() {
  var color = this.getAttribute("data-color");
  console.debug("Open new window with color: " + color);
  var myNewWindow = window.open();
  myNewWindow.document.body.style.background = color;
} 

var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener("change", openWindowWithColor);
}
```

Comment: i tried this, the new window was opening, but it was not displaying any background color.

Comment: It should work, tried it again right now using Firebug. Which browser are you using?

Comment: when i tried the example in Eclipse the output was not coming.. But the same example was working in normal editor. thank you...

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it could be that Eclipse manages the internal browser windows itself, so the JavaScript reference might get lost and you can't change anything in the new window from your initial context after opening it.

Comment: ok.. The new window bgcolor has to change after 2 seconds. For that setTimeout() function is there. but where i need to put that function?

Comment: See: http://jsbin.com/unikel/3/ - did you know that you can upvote answers and comments? :)

Comment: I think for that minimum reputation 15points. I does n't have that much

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function open(var color){
        //window.open("new_page.html#"+color);
        var myNewWindow = window.open("url");
        myNewWindow.document.body.style.background = color;
    }
</script>

<input type="radio" onclick="open('red')" />
<input type="radio" onclick="open('green')" />
<input type="radio" onclick="open('blue')" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var newwindow = window.open('popup.aspx','Color Popup','height=400,width=200');
newwindow.document.body.style.background = "#000";
```